# SVN / Apache Issue undefined symbol: apr_crypto_block_cleanup

Tags: apache, svn

I am using AlmaLinux 8 with svn/apache.

When trying to start my httpd service I am given the following status message:

`Aug 12 17:54:06 domain.tld httpd[495168]: httpd: Syntax error on line 132 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-svn.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache/mod_dav_svn.so into server: /usr/lib64/libsvn_subr-1.so.0: undefined symbol: apr_crypto_block_cleanup`

In the past, simply moving /usr/lib64/libsvn_subr-1.so.0 to /usr/lib64/libsvn_subr-1.so.0-old fixed the error but on this occasion (having updated dnf) this is not the case.

Struggling because I have limited debugging opportunities so if anything at all can be provided to help debug that would suffice as an answer. the only output I can find suitable for me is below.

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd13835000)
    libsvn_repos-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsvn_repos-1.so.0 (0x00007fb9de978000)
    libsvn_fs-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsvn_fs-1.so.0 (0x00007fb9de76a000)
    libsvn_fs_fs-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsvn_fs_fs-1.so.0 (0x00007fb9de512000)
    libsvn_fs_x-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsvn_fs_x-1.so.0 (0x00007fb9de2ba000)
    libsvn_delta-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsvn_delta-1.so.0 (0x00007fb9de09a000)
    libsvn_fs_util-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsvn_fs_util-1.so.0 (0x00007fb9dde96000)
    libsvn_subr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsvn_subr-1.so.0 (0x00007fb9ddc02000)
    libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/apache/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00007fb9dd9cd000)
    libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/apache/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007fb9dd788000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb9dd580000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fb9dd357000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fb9dd11c000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb9dcf05000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb9dcd01000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb9dcae1000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb9dc71c000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fb9dc408000)
    libmagic.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libmagic.so.1 (0x00007fb9dc1e1000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib64/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fb9dbfc4000)
    libutf8proc.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libutf8proc.so.2 (0x00007fb9dbd7b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb9dedea000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb9db9f9000)
```

Currently svn is only served via svn hence I don't even have svn available at cli.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following fixed my problem:

```
tar xvf subversion-1.14.0.tar.gz
cd subversion-1.14.0
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-amalgamation-3081101.zip -O sqlite-ation-3081101.zip
unzip sqlite-amalgamation-3081101.zip
mv sqlite-amalgamation-3081101 sqlite-amalgamation
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-lz4=internal --with-utf8proc=internal
make -j4
mv subversion/mod_dav_svn/.libs/mod_dav_svn.so /usr/lib/apache/mod_dav_svn.so
```

Thanks anyway, hope this helps someone (most likely me) in the future.

Edit: +1 to my previous self